# Practical uses of a Dynamic type in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Besides integration with dynamic languages on the JVM, what are the other powerful uses of a [Dynamic type](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/23993) in a statically typed language like Scala?

Comment: Without language support (e.g. `dynamic` in C#.4), I don't really "see" what's going on with that commit. Would be interesting to see how it fits in.

Comment: Th answers to this question are extremely outdated, for actual answers see: [How does type Dynamic work and how to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15799811/465304)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess a dynamic type could be used to implement several of the features found in JRuby, Groovy or other dynamic JVM languages, like dynamic metaprogramming and method_missing.

For example creating a dynamic query similar to Active Record in Rails, where a method name with parameters is translated to an SQL query in the background. This is using the method_missing functionality in Ruby. Something like this (in theory - have not tried to implement anything like this):

```
class Person(val id: Int) extends Dynamic {
  def _select_(name: String) = {
    val sql = "select " + name + " from Person where id = " id;
    // run sql and return result
  }

  def _invoke_(name: String)(args: Any*) = {
    val Pattern = "(findBy[a-zA-Z])".r
    val sql = name match {
      case Pattern(col) => "select * from Person where " + col + "='" args(0) + "'"
      case ...
    }
    // run sql and return result
  }
}
```

Allowing usage like this, where you can call methods 'name' and 'findByName' without having them explicitly defined in the Person class:

```
val person = new Person(1)

// select name from Person where id = 1
val name = person.name

// select * from Person where name = 'Bob'
val person2 = person.findByName("Bob")
```

If dynamic metaprogramming was to be added, the Dynamic type would be needed to allow invoking methods that have been added during runtime..

Comment: Shouldn't the third example you have use capital P: `Person.findByName("Bob")` ?

Answer (score 4):

Odersky says the primary motivation was integration with dynamic languages: http://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/msg/884e7f9a5351c549

[edit] Martin further confirms this [here](http://www.se-radio.net/2011/02/episode-171-scala-update-with-martin-odersky/)

Answer (score 2):

You might also use it for syntactic sugar on maps:

```
class DynamicMap[K, V] extends Dynamic {
  val self = scala.collection.mutable.Map[K, V]()
  def _select_(key: String) = self.apply(key)
  def _invoke_(key: String)(value: Any*) = 
    if (value.nonEmpty) self.update(key, value(0).asInstanceOf[V])
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException
}

val map = new DynamicMap[String, String]()

map.foo("bar")  // adds key "foo" with value "bar"    
map.foo         // returns "bar"
```

To be honest this only saves you a couple of keystrokes from:

```
val map = new Map[String, String]()
map("foo") = "bar"
map("foo")
```

Comment: Note that this example does not quite work for a couple of reasons, but I don't think there's much point in explorering this further before the feature is more stable.

Comment: I made it work here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876856/simple-scala-macro]