# What does the new scala Dynamic type do?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Practical uses of a Dynamic type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709183/practical-uses-of-a-dynamic-type-in-scala)

It has [just been tweeted](http://twitter.com/#!/ijuma/status/26758029940625408) that Martin Odersky has just added `Dynamic` into trunk. Apparently, **[this is HUGE](http://twitter.com/#!/jorgeortiz85/status/26762692656107520)**. Why?

Comment: Cheers - it didn't come up in my search. SO search is SO rubbish

Comment: This question is superseded now by [How does type Dynamic work and how to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15799811/465304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic adds developer driven dynamic binding (dynamic dispatch) and gives a subset of the features of dynamic typing to Scala.

See this pastie from Jorge Ortiz:

http://pastie.org/1469174

Comment: Get the illusion of static typing with none of the unsettling and unhappy development woes

Comment: You mean dynamic typing right? Scala has always had dynamic binding.

Comment: Scala has never had dynamic binding. The JVM internally has dynamic binding.

Comment: Viktor, are you just being nit-picking or do you really think there is no dynamic binding in Scala (or the bytecode it compiles to, which is equivalent)?

Comment: Raphael: Of course I am nitpicking.