# How does type Dynamic work and how to use it?

Tags: scala

I heard that with `Dynamic` it is somehow possible to do dynamic typing in Scala. But I can't imagine how that might look like or how it works.

I found out that one can inherit from trait `Dynamic`

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic
```

The [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic) says that one can use it like this:

> foo.method("blah")      ~~> foo.applyDynamic("method")("blah")

But when I try it out it doesn't work:

```
scala> (new DynImpl).method("blah")
<console>:17: error: value applyDynamic is not a member of DynImpl
error after rewriting to new DynImpl().<applyDynamic: error>("method")
possible cause: maybe a wrong Dynamic method signature?
              (new DynImpl).method("blah")
               ^
```

This is completely logical, because after looking to the [sources](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/Dynamic.scala), it turned out that this trait is completely empty. There is no method `applyDynamic` defined and I can't imagine how to implement it by myself.

Can someone show me what I need to do to make it to work?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Scalas type `Dynamic` allows you to call methods on objects that don't exist or in other words it is a replica of "method missing" in dynamic languages.

It is correct, [`scala.Dynamic`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/Dynamic.scala#L32) doesn't have any members, it is just a marker interface - the concrete implementation is filled-in by the compiler. As for Scalas [String Interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) feature there are well defined rules describing the generated implementation. In fact, one can implement four different methods:

- `selectDynamic` - allows to write field accessors: `foo.bar`
- `updateDynamic` - allows to write field updates: `foo.bar = 0`
- `applyDynamic` - allows to call methods with arguments: `foo.bar(0)`
- `applyDynamicNamed` - allows to call methods with named arguments: `foo.bar(f = 0)`

To use one of these methods it is enough to write a class that extends `Dynamic` and to implement the methods there:

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic {
  // method implementations here
}
```

Furthermore one need to add a

```
import scala.language.dynamics
```

or set the compiler option `-language:dynamics` because the feature is hidden by default.

### selectDynamic

`selectDynamic` is the easiest one to implement. The compiler translates a call of `foo.bar` to `foo.selectDynamic("bar")`, thus it is required that this method has an argument list expecting a `String`:

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic {
  def selectDynamic(name: String) = name
}

scala> val d = new DynImpl
d: DynImpl = DynImpl@6040af64

scala> d.foo
res37: String = foo

scala> d.bar
res38: String = bar

scala> d.selectDynamic("foo")
res54: String = foo
```

As one can see, it is also possible to call the dynamic methods explicitly.

### updateDynamic

Because `updateDynamic` is used to update a value this method needs to return `Unit`. Furthermore, the name of the field to update and its value are passed to different argument lists by the compiler:

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic {

  var map = Map.empty[String, Any]

  def selectDynamic(name: String) =
    map get name getOrElse sys.error("method not found")

  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: Any) {
    map += name -> value
  }
}

scala> val d = new DynImpl
d: DynImpl = DynImpl@7711a38f

scala> d.foo
java.lang.RuntimeException: method not found

scala> d.foo = 10
d.foo: Any = 10

scala> d.foo
res56: Any = 10
```

The code works as expected - it is possible to add methods at runtime to the code. On the other side, the code isn't typesafe anymore and if a method is called that doesn't exist this must be handled at runtime as well. In addition this code is not as useful as in dynamic languages because it is not possible to create the methods that should be called at runtime. This means that we can't do something like

```
val name = "foo"
d.$name
```

where `d.$name` would be transformed to `d.foo` at runtime. But this is not that bad because even in dynamic languages this is a dangerous feature.

Another thing to note here, is that `updateDynamic` needs to be implemented together with `selectDynamic`. If we don't do this we will get a compile error - this rule is similar to the implementation of a Setter, which only works if there is a Getter with the same name.

### applyDynamic

The ability to call methods with arguments is provided by `applyDynamic`:

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) =
    s"method '$name' called with arguments ${args.mkString("'", "', '", "'")}"
}

scala> val d = new DynImpl
d: DynImpl = DynImpl@766bd19d

scala> d.ints(1, 2, 3)
res68: String = method 'ints' called with arguments '1', '2', '3'

scala> d.foo()
res69: String = method 'foo' called with arguments ''

scala> d.foo
<console>:19: error: value selectDynamic is not a member of DynImpl
```

The name of the method and its arguments again are separated to different parameter lists. We can call arbitrary methods with an arbitrary number of arguments if we want but if we want to call a method without any parentheses we need to implement `selectDynamic`.

Hint: It is also possible to use apply-syntax with `applyDynamic`:

```
scala> d(5)
res1: String = method 'apply' called with arguments '5'
```

### applyDynamicNamed

The last available method allows us to name our arguments if we want:

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic {

  def applyDynamicNamed(name: String)(args: (String, Any)*) =
    s"method '$name' called with arguments ${args.mkString("'", "', '", "'")}"
}

scala> val d = new DynImpl
d: DynImpl = DynImpl@123810d1

scala> d.ints(i1 = 1, i2 = 2, 3)
res73: String = method 'ints' called with arguments '(i1,1)', '(i2,2)', '(,3)'
```

The difference in the method signature is that `applyDynamicNamed` expects tuples of the form `(String, A)` where `A` is an arbitrary type.

---

All of the above methods have in common that their parameters can be parameterized:

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic {

  import reflect.runtime.universe._

  def applyDynamic[A : TypeTag](name: String)(args: A*): A = name match {
    case "sum" if typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[Int] =>
      args.asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]].sum.asInstanceOf[A]
    case "concat" if typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[String] =>
      args.mkString.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}

scala> val d = new DynImpl
d: DynImpl = DynImpl@5d98e533

scala> d.sum(1, 2, 3)
res0: Int = 6

scala> d.concat("a", "b", "c")
res1: String = abc
```

Luckily, it is also possible to add implicit arguments - if we add a [`TypeTag`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it) context bound we can easily check the types of the arguments. And the best thing is that even the return type is correct - even though we had to add some casts.

But Scala would not be Scala when there is no way to find a way around such flaws. In our case we can use type classes to avoid the casts:

```
object DynTypes {
  sealed abstract class DynType[A] {
    def exec(as: A*): A
  }

  implicit object SumType extends DynType[Int] {
    def exec(as: Int*): Int = as.sum
  }

  implicit object ConcatType extends DynType[String] {
    def exec(as: String*): String = as.mkString
  }
}

class DynImpl extends Dynamic {

  import reflect.runtime.universe._
  import DynTypes._

  def applyDynamic[A : TypeTag : DynType](name: String)(args: A*): A = name match {
    case "sum" if typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[Int] =>
      implicitly[DynType[A]].exec(args: _*)
    case "concat" if typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[String] =>
      implicitly[DynType[A]].exec(args: _*)
  }

}
```

While the implementation doesn't look that nice, its power can't be questioned:

```
scala> val d = new DynImpl
d: DynImpl = DynImpl@24a519a2

scala> d.sum(1, 2, 3)
res89: Int = 6

scala> d.concat("a", "b", "c")
res90: String = abc
```

At the top of all, it is also possible to combine `Dynamic` with macros:

```
class DynImpl extends Dynamic {
  import language.experimental.macros

  def applyDynamic[A](name: String)(args: A*): A = macro DynImpl.applyDynamic[A]
}
object DynImpl {
  import reflect.macros.Context
  import DynTypes._

  def applyDynamic[A : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(name: c.Expr[String])(args: c.Expr[A]*) = {
    import c.universe._

    val Literal(Constant(defName: String)) = name.tree

    val res = defName match {
      case "sum" if weakTypeOf[A] =:= weakTypeOf[Int] =>
        val seq = args map(_.tree) map { case Literal(Constant(c: Int)) => c }
        implicitly[DynType[Int]].exec(seq: _*)
      case "concat" if weakTypeOf[A] =:= weakTypeOf[String] =>
        val seq = args map(_.tree) map { case Literal(Constant(c: String)) => c }
        implicitly[DynType[String]].exec(seq: _*)
      case _ =>
        val seq = args map(_.tree) map { case Literal(Constant(c)) => c }
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"method '$defName' with args ${seq.mkString("'", "', '", "'")} doesn't exist")
    }
    c.Expr(Literal(Constant(res)))
  }
}

scala> val d = new DynImpl
d: DynImpl = DynImpl@c487600

scala> d.sum(1, 2, 3)
res0: Int = 6

scala> d.concat("a", "b", "c")
res1: String = abc

scala> d.noexist("a", "b", "c")
<console>:11: error: method 'noexist' with args 'a', 'b', 'c' doesn't exist
              d.noexist("a", "b", "c")
                       ^
```

Macros give us back all compile time guarantees and while it is not that useful in the above case, maybe it can be very useful for some Scala DSLs.

If you want to get even more information about `Dynamic` there are some more resources:

- The [official SIP proposal](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/type-dynamic.html) that introduced `Dynamic` into Scala
- [Practical uses of a Dynamic type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709183/practical-uses-of-a-dynamic-type-in-scala) - another question on SO (but very outdated)

Comment: I wouldn't call it _power_ in case the feature is hidden by default, e.g. might be experimental or not play well with others, or does it?

Comment: Is there any information on the performance of Scala Dynamic? I know Scala Reflection is slow (thus comes Scala-macro). Will the use of Scala Dynamic slow down performance dramatically?

Comment: @AllenNie As you can see in my answer, there are different ways to implement it. If you use macros, there is no overhead anymore, since the dynamic call is resolved at compile time. If you use do checks at runtime, you have to do the parameter checking in order to dispatch correctly to the right code path. That shouldn't be more overhead than any other parameter checking in your application has. If you make use of reflection, you get obviously more overhead but you have to measure by yourself how much it slows down your application.

Comment: Very well written, but one mistake in it, you stated `d.$name` could not be done, but of course it can with a more verbose syntax as `d.selectDynamic(name)`. And the same goes for the other `*Dynamic` definitions.

Comment: @kiritsuku there is a little mistake regarding `updateDynamic`: as `someProp_=(value: Ty): Int` can return something, so can `updateDynamic`. So it's not true that it **needs** to return `Unit`. Otherwise perfect answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

kiritsuku's answer is better.  This is to show a practical TL;DR use case.

Dynamics can be used to dynamically construct an object with the builder pattern.

```scala
import scala.language.dynamics

case class DynImpl(
  inputParams: Map[String, List[String]] = Map.empty[String, List[String]]
) extends Dynamic {

  def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: String*): DynImpl = {
    copy(inputParams = inputParams ++ Map(name -> args.toList))
  }

}

val d1 = DynImpl().whatever("aaa", "bbb").cool("ccc")
println(d1.inputParams) // Map(whatever -> List(aaa, bbb), cool -> List(ccc))

val d2 = DynImpl().whatever("aaa", "bbb").fun("haha")
println(d2.inputParams) // Map(whatever -> List(aaa, bbb), fun -> List(haha))
```