# Scala function type with variable list of arguments of any type

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a generic function parameter, that would accept any arguments, and return any result. I want to create a more dynamic environment to call them, so for example I have this code:

```
object Environment {
  type Func = (Any *) => (Any)

  def apply(): Environment = new Environment(Map(
    "sin" -> math.sin,
    "cos" -> math.cos,
    "tan" -> math.tan,
    "pi" -> Function.const(math.Pi),
    "sqrt" -> math.sqrt
 ))
}
```

This causes a mismatch error, if I change the Func type to:

```
type Func = (Nothing *) => (Any)
```

it works, but then I can't call the function like:

```
environment.symbols("cos").apply(0)
```

because of a type mismatch but this time when calling apply.

My question is, if there is any way to call these functions in a more dynamic way, without type checking?

Comment: Would something like `environment.symbolse("pi").apply(())` be an acceptable comprimise?

Comment: Use type [Dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799811/how-does-type-dynamic-work-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment: I'll have a look at Dynamic. First time seeing it. Thanks