# What is a marker Trait in Scala that enables dynamic invocations?

Tags: scala, traits

I was reading about Scala

> A marker trait that enables dynamic invocations. Instances x of this trait allow method invocations x.meth(args) for arbitrary method names meth and argument lists args as well as field accesses x.field for arbitrary field namesfield. This feature is introduced in Scala-2.10.

**Source**:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_basic_syntax.htm

I have no idea what this means. **Please provide a simple explanation**!

Comment: It's all in here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/type-dynamic.html

Comment: Advice - Do not try to learn Scala from tutorials point (it is low quality and out-dated). You can read the book `http://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_3ed` if you need a thorough reading. Or if you already have done some function programming before then you can read Scala School by Twitter.

Comment: Take a look at this answer I think it is quite related http://stackoverflow.com/q/15799811/1553233

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does type Dynamic work and how to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799811/how-does-type-dynamic-work-and-how-to-use-it)