# How to dynamically create an Enum type in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums

I have a basic enum type Currency that will include all major currencies traded e.g. `EUR`, `USD`, `JPY`, etc. This code I can write or generate one time. However, I'd also like to have strong enum type for all currency pair combinations e.g. `EURCHF`, `USDCHF`, etc. Is there any provision in Scala that would allow me to build such a derived enum type dynamically? I could also do it with some script generator from outside ... but I wonder whether it would be possible.

```
object Ccy extends Enumeration {
   type Type = Value
   val USD = Value("USD")
   val CHF = Value("CHF")
   val EUR = Value("EUR")
   val GBP = Value("GBP")
   val JPY = Value("JPY")
}

object CcyPair extends Enumeration {
   type Type = Value
   // ??? Ccy.values.toSeq.combinations(2) ...   
}
```

**UPDATE** using the accepted answer as reference this was my solution implementation:

```
import scala.language.dynamics

object CcyPair extends Enumeration with Dynamic {
  type Type = Value
  /* 
   * contains all currency combinations including the symmetric AB and BA
   */
  private val byCcy: Map[(Ccy.Value, Ccy.Value), Value] =
    Ccy.values.toSeq.combinations(2).map { case Seq(c1, c2) =>
      Seq(
        (c1, c2) -> Value(c1.toString + c2.toString),
        (c2, c1) -> Value(c2.toString + c1.toString)
      )
    }.flatten.toMap
  /** 
   * reverse lookup to find currencies by currency pair, needed to find
   * the base and risk components.
   */ 
  private val revByCcy = byCcy.toSeq.map { case (((ccyRisk, ccyBase), ccyPair)) =>
    ccyPair -> (ccyRisk, ccyBase)
  }.toMap

  def apply(ccy1: Ccy.Value, ccy2: Ccy.Value): Value = {
    assert(ccy1 != ccy2, "currencies should be different")
    byCcy((ccy1, ccy2))
  }

  implicit class DecoratedCcyPair(ccyPair: CcyPair.Type) {
    def base: Ccy.Type = {
      revByCcy(ccyPair)._1
    }

    def risk: Ccy.Type = {
      revByCcy(ccyPair)._2
    }

    def name: String = ccyPair.toString()
  }

  def selectDynamic(ccyPair: String): Value = withName(ccyPair)
}
```

and then I can do things like:

```
val ccyPair = CcyPair.EURUSD
// or
val ccyPair = CcyPair(Ccy.EUR, Ccy.USD) 

// and then do
println(ccyPair.name)
// and extract their parts like:
// print the base currency of the pair i.e. EUR
println(CcyPair.EURUSD.base) 
// print the risk currency of the pair i.e. USD
println(CcyPair.EURUSD.risk)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no magic in Scala's `Enumeration`. The call to the `Value` function inside simply does some modifications to `Enumeration`'s internal mutable structures. So you just have to call `Value` for each pair of currencies. The following code will work:

```
object CcyPair1 extends Enumeration {
  Ccy.values.toSeq.combinations(2).foreach {
    case Seq(c1, c2) =>
      Value(c1.toString + c2.toString)
  }
}
```

It's not very comfortable to work with though. You can access the values only through `withName` or `values` functions.

```
scala> CcyPair1.withName("USDEUR")
res20: CcyPair1.Value = USDEUR
```

But it's possible to extend this definition, for example, to allow retrieving `CcyPair.Value` by a pair of `Ccy.Value`s, or to allow access by object fields with `Dynamic`, or to provide other facilities you may need:

```
import scala.language.dynamics

object CcyPair2 extends Enumeration with Dynamic {
  val byCcy: Map[(Ccy.Value, Ccy.Value), Value] =
    Ccy.values.toSeq.combinations(2).map {
      case Seq(c1, c2) =>
        (c1, c2) -> Value(c1.toString + c2.toString)
    }.toMap

  def forCcy(ccy1: Ccy.Value, ccy2: Ccy.Value): Value = {
    assert(ccy1 != ccy2, "currencies should be different")
    if (ccy1 < ccy2) byCcy((ccy1, ccy2))
    else byCcy((ccy2, ccy1))
  }

  def selectDynamic(pairName: String): Value =
    withName(pairName)
}
```

This definition is a bit more useful:

```
scala> CcyPair2.forCcy(Ccy.USD, Ccy.EUR)
res2: CcyPair2.Value = USDEUR

scala> CcyPair2.forCcy(Ccy.EUR, Ccy.USD)
res3: CcyPair2.Value = USDEUR

scala> CcyPair2.USDCHF
res4: CcyPair2.Value = USDCHF
```

Comment: Hold a sec .... in your answer you do `CcyPair2.USDCHF` and is magically defined but for me doesn't exist ...

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Yes, that's because the definition of `CcyPair2` extends `Dynamic`, and has `selectDynamic` overridden. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799811/how-does-type-dynamic-work-and-how-to-use-it for more explanation. It may not be a good idea to use it here, because it will result in runtime errors instead of compile time, I've just given it as an example.

Comment: Ah yes sorry indeed I missed extending `Dynamic` and the required import.

Comment: I think this dynamic approach is a good trade off. I don't have compile time check of existence understandably so but with good test coverage all the runtime mistakes will be caught ... at least it will not be as involved and error prone as testing the equivalent `String` based solution