# simple scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-2.10

I would like to have a scala macro that does the following:
When I write:

```
myCreateCityMacro("paris")
myCreateCityMacro("vallorbe")
```

I would like to get:

```
val paris = new City("paris")
val vallorbe = new City("vallorbe")
```

Comment: `val x = new X("x")` is not a simple expression in Scala and so, can't be returned by a macro as you wonder. I think the best approach for your case is `val x = city`, being _city_ a macro that infers the name of the city by inspecting the prefix of the context invocation.

Comment: Ops, I was mistaken, the `context.prefix` can't access the name of the val.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using scala Dynamic feature:

```
import scala.language.dynamics

object Cities extends App {
    var c = new DynamicMap[String, City]()
    createCity("Paris")
    createCity("Vallorbe")
    println(c.Paris, c.Vallorbe)

    def createCity(name: String) {
        c.self.update(name, new City(name))
    }
}

class City(name: String) {
    override def toString = s"-[$name]-"
}

class DynamicMap[K, V] extends Dynamic {
    val self = scala.collection.mutable.Map[K, V]()
    def selectDynamic(key: K) = self(key)
}
```

when executing:

```
(-[Paris]-,-[Vallorbe]-)
```